# How to lock viewController in Portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, ios9.1

I am woking on iOS application in swift. I have used UITabBarController as a rootViewController. I have list of videos in one viewController. This viewController supports only portrait mode and user select a video then enter playerController using showViewController method, that can support both orientation (Portrait and Landscape mode). If video finished then playerController pop to video list controller.Every things is fine but user can rotate screen during the finishing the video(like remaining time 1 or 0 second) then video list viewController enter in Landscape mode.
I have tried this code for set player orientation in portrait mode.

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

But not worked. How to fixed this issue.

Answer (score 6):

To lock a viewController in a mode do the following:

In your AppDeletegate add:

```
var shouldSupportAllOrientation = false
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if (shouldSupportAllOrientation == true){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

Now go to each view and add the following in `viewWillAppear`:

**Portait mode only**

```
let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appdelegate.shouldSupportAllOrientation = false
```

**All modes**

```
let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appdelegate.shouldSupportAllOrientation = true
```

**Update**
If you want to go from landscape back to portrait again when you change view/tab, add the following code

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

**Swift 3.x version**
**Add this in your AppDelegate class**

```
var shouldSupportAllOrientation = false
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if (shouldSupportAllOrientation == true){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}
```

**Add this in your viewController**

```
// Portrait mode
let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appdelegate.shouldSupportAllOrientation = false

// All modes
let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appdelegate.shouldSupportAllOrientation = true
```

## Swift 4 version:

In your AppDelegate, add the following:

```
var shouldSupportOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return shouldSupportOrientation
}
```

In each viewController add the following:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appdelegate.shouldSupportOrientation = .portrait // set desired orientation

    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue // set desired orientation
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

This will lock your view and rotate it.

Comment: Have you added the above code in AppDeletegate and each ViewController that you have? Have you added breakpoints and checked that these code blocks actually are running?

Comment: Yes, I have added above code in AppDelegate and each viewController. And also checked with break points, AppDelegate method call as we expected but not worked as i expected.

Comment: Does any viewController get locked when you´re calling the Portait mode only snippet?

Comment: Yes, but this problem is generate, if video is finishing and orientation will changed then locked viewController entered in landscape mode.

Comment: If you have Portrait only and then open a view and you can rotate the video to Landscape, when you close the video you should should return to portrait again.

Comment: Yes, my requirement is like this.

Comment: What kind of video are you trying to open? I have this functionality in my application and I open an embedded YouTube URL and it goes back to portrait when I´m done.

Comment: I am playing video from URL  and using AVPlayerViewController to play video.

Comment: I don't know, Why this problem is generating.

Comment: But this orientation code that I wrote above works, right?

Comment: Did you find any solution @vipulk617

Comment: No, I have not found any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You first must go to your general project settings and make sure your "Device Orientation" is set to Portrait (and optionally Upside Down)

[image]

Then In the info.pList file,

Check the key Supported interface orientations. Delete all its keys except the only portrait key. Review the below image for it.

[image]

This will force your app to run in portrait. Even when you close your player in landscape mode, your app will move back to portrait mode.