# How to make one ViewController portrait only in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I have an application that supports bot portrait and landscape for iPad and portrait only for iPhone. I like to make one ViewController as portrait only for iPad. Is this possible?

Comment: Checkout my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34489983/5576310) it will help you.

Comment: That works. Appreciate it

Comment: Np, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

add this in all your ViewController

```
if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.phone)
    {
        func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
            return true
        }


    }
```