# programmably setting orientation in "Swift3"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I did know how to fix orientation when I'm coding swift2, but after they changed their function into 'var', that new code doesn't work.

here is the sample UIViewController class for a check

```
class QuizVC: UIViewController{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Quiz scene
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 238/255, blue: 226/255, alpha: 1)//sand fron hu

    let testBtn: UIButton = UIButton()//for orientation test
    testBtn.setTitle("\" OrientationCheck \"", for: .normal)
    testBtn.sizeToFit()
    testBtn.center = self.view.center
    testBtn.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    testBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    self.view.addSubview(testBtn)
    //Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {//not working
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
}
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {//not working
    return false
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}}
```

When I run this code, it seems just ignoring that override.
View rotates automatically, buttons and labels don't showed as landscape orientation. And not even fixed.

I also tried to put orientation value directly into the variable, but 'supportedInterfaceOrientations' is get-only property.
Of course, old codes accepted as an error, because there are no longer function called 'supportedInterfaceOrientations()'. Only variable exists.

Are there anyone tried this in Swift3?

I'm using swift3 on iOS10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lock viewController in Portrait mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489764/how-to-lock-viewcontroller-in-portrait-mode)

Answer (score 0):

1. remove shouldAutorotate
2. enable landscape in (app setting page)/general/device orientation

this should be work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct AppUtility {

  static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {

    if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
      delegate.orientationLock = orientation
    }
  }

  /// OPTIONAL Added method to adjust lock and rotate to the desired orientation
  static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {

    self.lockOrientation(orientation)

    UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
  }

}
```

Add the above class in your project.

AppUtility.lockOrientation(.landscape, andRotateTo: .portrait)