# Swift 3 - How to lock orientation for iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm trying to create an app that only supports portrait orientation, I have tried setting at **Target -> General -> Deployment Info -> Portrait**

Then, at **appDelegate.swift**

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```

AT **ViewController.swift**

```
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait ]
    }
```

But it doesn't work.. At ViewController.swift, it give me **error**:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

Comment: Select a target and find Device Orientation under Deplayment info.

Comment: Have you unchecked all other orientations in Deployment Info except for Portrait?

Comment: Yes I did, I even clear the landscape out at info.plist  --> supported interface orientations

Comment: In Swift 3 this functions was replaced by an property. override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    } (note the var instead of func)

Comment: @JohnFoong, checkout my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34489983/5576310) it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

**In Swift 3.1**

If you want to lock orientation on all of the screen.

See also https://freakycoder.com/ios-notes-5-how-to-application-orientation-abba750bed6e .

Open AppDelegate.swift, and add this code.

```
// Lock the orientation to Portrait mode
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait.rawValue)
}
```

or

```
// Lock the orientation to Landscape(Horizontal) mode
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape.rawValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple code just copy and paste the following code in the ViewController you want to fix the Orientation for.

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

This works if and only if all the code is in the ViewController, no need to change anything or put anything in the AppDelegate. Cheers